# Mysql query to select all images based on pixel size

Tags: java, mysql, spring

I'm sorry if this question is too straight forward as this is not a problem I'm struggling with right now but more like a question whether it is possible.

So, I'm a manual QA and was wondering if I can use Mysql to search all images on our website database (sorry if not proper expression) that have a size bigger than certain witdh and height parameters?

Also, if that is not possible, if it is possible to be implemented a featuer (backend is on java spring) to be written, that would allow to store images with and height in the database in case that is not done automaticly - if mysql cant query the above idea.

And, if above option possible, to set a feature for the admin panel in which to be able to search and list image size + filter based on other parameters (based on image association with different sectors of the site)

Comment: Do you keep metatadata on the images in your database? We have zero idea what your schema looks like, so it's not possible to say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question sounds more like a request for an opinion on various possibilities. So, let's explore each possibility:

"**if I can use Mysql to search all images on our website database**"
 - This depends on whether or not the image information is stored in a mysql database. If it is, then yes absolutely you can search all images.

"**if it is possible to be implemented a featuer (backend is on java spring) to be written, that would allow to store images with and height in the database**"
 - That is absolutely possible and if it is not done already, it is required to achieve the result desired above.

" **to set a feature for the admin panel in which to be able to search and list image size + filter based on other parameters**"
- Once you have either of the solutions above in place, the information is stored in the database and can be queried just like any other data. It can be combined with with criteria based on other information stored in the database - as long as the other data has a direct or indirect relation to the images.

This answer may not provide much technical information, but there are very little specifics.